# Artisan Fatal error when trying to install Laravel FFMpeg

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, composer-php

I am trying to include pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg package in my Laravel app but for some reason when I run `composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg` I receive this error:

```
composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg
Using version ^1.1 for pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_Font' not found in /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/config/excel.php:182
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(60): require()
#1 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(38): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Illuminate\Config\Repository))
#2 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#3 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(267): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#4 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illu in /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/config/excel.php on line 182

Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_Font' not found in /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/config/excel.php:182
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(60): require()
#1 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(38): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Illuminate\Config\Repository))
#2 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#3 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(267): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#4 /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illu in /Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/config/excel.php on line 182
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

my composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much,
Chris

Comment: In `/Users/chrisbreuer/code/clooud/config/excel.php:182`
Composer is trying to autoload `PHPExcel_Shared_Font` class which it was unable to resolve. I don't think laravel-ffmpeg has anything to do with it.